# Delegate not informing my View

Tags: objective-c, ios7, delegates

My cpViewController has a button that modal segues to cpScanViewController.  I want to have cpScanViewController inform ViewController with a string when it has completed a successful scan.  After reading numerous articles online,  I believe delegation is the best way to do this?

1. Is the delegate being set correctly?
2. How does the delegate inform the cpViewController?

cpScanViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@protocol ScanDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)receivedUPC:(NSString *)Scan;
@end

@interface cpScanViewController : UIViewController 
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ScanDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *UPC;
-(void)checkUPC;
@end
```

cpScanViewController.m

```
@interface cpScanViewController ()
{
  NSString *UPC;
}
@end

@implementation cpScanViewController
@synthesize delegate;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
-(void)doSomeScanStuff
{
UPC = @"a string"
   // even tried
 [delegate receivedUPC:UPC];
}
-(void)checkUPC
{

}
@end
```

cpViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "cpScanViewController.h"

@interface cpViewController : UIViewController <ScanDelegate>

@end
```

cpViewController.m

```
@interface cpViewController ()
{
 cpScanViewController *cp;
}
@end

@implementation cpViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  // set delegate
cp = [[cpScanViewController alloc] init];
[cp setDelegate:self];

}
-(void)receivedUPC:(NSString *)Scan{
  // Nothing happening
NSLog(@"%@", Scan);    
NSLog(@"The %@", cp.UPC);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by using the method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    cpScanViewController *vd = (cpScanViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
vd.delegate = self;
}
```

Because I made the connection in storyboards I didn't realize it needed to have the method.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not calling `receivedUPC` method from your `cpScanViewController` class. You need to add `[_delegate receivedUPC:self]`, some where in order to invoke this delegat method in `cpViewController` class.

Comment: adding [delegate receivedUPC:self]; to the viewDidLoad in cpScanViewController produces and warning Incompatible pointer types sending 'cpScanViewController *' to parameter of type 'Scanner *'.